# Get values of keywords from a string and a template in Python

Tags: python, python-2.7

Finally I have the solution following the example by @jonrsharpe and I present it here. It works for me except that I need to use os.path.split to split the folder and filename to ensure the uniqueness of the keywords in the templates.

```
def parse_kwdict(s, template, keys, kwmark='$'):
    kw2rekw = {key:'(?P<'+key+'>.*)' for key in keys}
    pattern = replace(template, kw2rekw, kwmark=kwmark)
    return re.match(pattern, s).groupdict()

def replace(template, kwdict, kwmark='$'):
    name = template
    for key, val in kwdict.iteritems():
        if val is not None:
            name = name.replace(kwmark+key, str(val))
    return name
```

==== Below is my question.

I have data stored in different directory trees.

It could be like

`/parent/folder/$year/$day/$location/$sensor..$freq.$year.$day.dat`

or

`/parent/folder/$sensor/$year.$day/$sensor.$location.$year.$day.dat`

or ...

I wanna define a function like

```
def parse_kwdict(s, template, keys, kwmark='$'):
    do somthing here
    return kwdict
```

so that I can extract the values for the keys from the string and template.

For example,

```
template = '/parent/folder/$sensor/$year.$day/$freq/$sensor.$location.$year.$day.dat'
keys = ['year', 'day', 'location', 'sensor', 'freq'] # keywords in the template
s = '/parent/folder/SensorA/2011.123/5Hz/SensorA.E.2011.123.dat'
kwdict = parse_kwdict(s, template, keys)
```

give rise to

```
kwdict = {'year':2011, 'day':123, 'location':'E', 'sensor':'SensorA', 'freq':'5Hz'}
```

Some notes for my cases to deal with,

1. there is **no space** in the values of keywords.
2. there is always some delimiter like letters, dot, underscore, slash **between the keywords** in the template.
3. the keywords in the template are listed in `keys` (keyword='$'+key) and they are quite different. There won't be keywords like `$freq` and `$frequency` which make obscurity.
4. the keywords include letters only, no special characters.
5. the values for keywords include letters and digits, no special characters, but could also be ''.
6. a keyword can appear one or more times in the template and string, or also can be absent. If a keyword appears more than once, the values in the string are the same.

Comment: What are you actually trying to achieve, here? Why not just use the regular `repr` format, which you can easily parse with `ast.literal_eval`?

Comment: @jonrsharpe  I guess my first illustration about the forward replacement from a template confused you. What I need is when I have a string, a template, and the list of keywords in the template, how do I get the values for the keywords from the string?

Comment: Again, what is the *purpose*? What have you tried, and what exactly is the problem with it?

Comment: @Dr.Lee How do you expect to reverse it reliably anyway? Take an expanded string of "his" for instance - is the re-templated version "$bis" or "$a" ?

Comment: according to the given condition, there may be many answers. Suppose `s='This is_an_example.'`, `template='T$a$b_an_$c'`, and keys of `kwdict` is `['a','b','c']`, the answer can be `{'a':'his ', 'b':'is', 'c':'example.'}` as you mentioned, however, answer `{'a':'h', 'b':'is is', 'c':'example.'}` is also right

Comment: How exactly do you want to define your "capturing groups"? `$` plus a letter? It is not clear to me whether `$hey_there` should return a key for `$h` or `$hey`. Anyway, it seems to me you are approaching a simple problem with a cumbersome solution.

Comment: @bgusach the keywords are defined in the list of `keys` and they are quite different.  Maybe you are correct I haven't got the correct way.

Comment: What if you have a key `a` and another `aa`? how is `$aa` going to be interpreted, as the first or the second?. What do you want this for?

Comment: @bgusach sorry. there are no similar keywords making obscurity. It was a typo.

Comment: To @jonrsharpe and others: I updated the question to illustrate the real situation I need to deal with. You are correct the extraction is non-unique in a general case. But for my needs it should be unique

Comment: And do you know *a priori* what kinds of things each token represents (e.g. `$freq` will always be an integerfollowed by `Hz`, or `\d+Hz` in regex)?

Comment: @jonrsharpe there is no guarantee that $freq=number+'Hz', but as mentioned in the notes, between the keywords there are always some delimiters like '.', '..', '_' or '/'. A keyword can appear one or more times, or even be absent.

Comment: @jonrsharpe that's because there are several data source. They don't have a uniform criteria on the directory tree......

Comment: *"A keyword can appear one or more times"* - but can only appear once in the output dictionary...

Comment: @jonrsharpe I meant in the template (and the string), one keyword is possible to appear more than once. But the value in the string must be the same.

Comment: Yes, and therefore how will you handle that in `kwdict`?

Comment: @jonrsharpe the values in the string are the same for the same keyword and of course one keyword appear only once in  `kwdict`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a generic example of the kind of approach you could take; how much adaptation it will require to meet your needs is not wholly clear to me. Basically it's converting from your `$`-based template string to an regex pattern with named capture groups, then using that to extract the data from an actual path:

```
>>> import re

>>> template = '/parent/folder/$freq/$name.dat'  # base template
>>> parts = {
    'freq': r'(?P<freq>\d+Hz)',  # one or more digits then Hz
    'name': r'(?P<name>[a-z]{3,8})',  # three to eight lowercase letters
}  # patterns for the parts of the template

>>> pattern = re.sub(
    r'\$([^/.]+)',  # dollar followed by characters excluding / and .
    lambda match: parts[match.group(1)], 
    template
)  # re.sub creates the pattern to match the actual path
>>> pattern
'/parent/folder/(?P<freq>\\d+Hz)/(?P<name>[a-z]{3,8}).dat'

>>> re.match(
    pattern,     
    '/parent/folder/5Hz/hello.dat'
).groupdict()  # re.match extracts the appropriate data
{'freq': '5Hz', 'name': 'hello'}
```

Note that dictionary keys must be unique, so if e.g. `$year` appears twice in your template you will have to come up with some way to distinguish the two values.

Answer (score 0):

Short story: you cannot (in the general case) reliably reverse the merge, your first example was explicit: `template = 'T$a$b_an_$c'` `string = 'This is_an_example'` could give `a='' b='his is'`, `a='h' b='is is'`, `a='hi' b='s is'`, etc.

Long story:

- you first need to parse the template to identify fixed portions and replaceable tokens: replaceable tokens are `$` followed by a single lower case character in the range `a-z`, fixed are all what remains
- then you need to escape all special characters (at least `.?(){}\:` maybe others) in fixed parts
- then you build a regex by replacing replaceable tokens in template by `.*` and the fixed parts by their escaped values
- matching the string to the regex should give one possible mapping (there may be others) if the match was possible. **Beware**: there could be other possibilities

You could try to use *ungreedy* matches (`.*?` instead of `.*`). If you get exactly same solution that you got with greedy searches, the solution should be unique - more exactly, I'm not really sure about that, but just could not imagine an example where it would be false

Last remarks for your last edit:

- if keywords are not single letters, **you** must specify how they can be identified (it is not only by chance that shell designers imagined `${xxz}`)
- template `'/AAA/$a.$b.$c.txt'` would not give unique results with above method: `/AAA/x.y.z.t.txt` could give `{ 'a' : 'x.y', 'b': 'z', 'c': 't' }` (gready), or `{ 'a' : 'x', 'b': 'y', 'c': 'z.t' }` (ungreedy)

Comment: Thx @SergeBallesta I update my question to discard some obscurities.